# What phrase from natural language does the letter "**t**" in `\tfrac` stand for?

Tags: fractions, documentation

I saw someone use `\tfrac` in one of their documents.

```latex
\text{young children are often taught }  \tfrac 18  \text{ is  } \tfrac 12 \text{ of } \tfrac 14
```

[image: a screen capture of rendered LaTeX output]

As two examples of what I am looking for, we have:

> 1. `quad` could be written as `spazio quadratone`
> 2. `dfrac` is `display fraction`

So... `tfrac` is... what exactly? ... In one of the languages English, French, Italian, German, etc...

Comment: `text fraction` perhaps?

Comment: apart from the name, the syntax is `\tfrac{1}{8}`  not `\tfrac18` (although that does unfortunately work)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I nominate "although that does unfortunately work" for the hall of fame.

Comment: BTW: Section 4.11 of the `amsmath` manual `amsldoc.pdf` already explains: *The amsmath package provides also \dfrac and \tfrac as convenient abbreviations for `{\displaystyle\frac ... }` and `{\textstyle\frac ... }`.* And before you're asking `\genfrac` is *generalized fraction* (see section 4.11.3 of the amsmath manual).

Answer (score 5):

- The `t` in `\tfrac` and `\tbinom` stands for "**t**ext style" frac/binom
- The `d` in `\dfrac` and `\dbinom` stands for "**d**isplay style" frac/binom

TeX provides four main math "styles":

- `\displaystyle`, default in displayed math material
- `\textstyle`, default in inline math material
- `\scriptstyle`, default in first-level subscripts and superscripts
- `\scriptscriptstyle`, default in second-level subscripts and superscripts

Comment: Note that `\textstyle` is, as Mico noted, for inline `math` material. Fractions would not be written vertically (usually) in flowing book text, due to line spacing issues. In fact, non-math literature would spell it, "one-eighth".