# What English words does the `d` in `dfrac` represent?

Tags: tex-history, latex-history

When creating LaTeX language packages for use in by French  mathematicians, German ,
chinese mathematicians   and other mathematicians, it is helpful to know what English words various LaTeX commands were derived from.

For example, a Chinese mathematician might have difficulty translating `dfrac` from English into Chinese (or Putonghua).

What is `dfrac` when spelled out in full English words?

Comment: to be fair it's already answered in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135389/what-is-the-difference-between-dfrac-and-frac which is the first (for me) search result on `site:tex.stackexchange.com dfrac`

Comment: [Mico has already answered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/684515/277964) this at [your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/684514/277964). And once again, before you'll ask about `\genfrac` see my comment to that question.

Comment: This is not a "do it for me" site. What do you think "dfrac" might be an abbreviation of? --- "display fraction", "different factor", "demonitated fiddle",  You should show that you have given some thought to your perceived problem.

Answer (score 1):

`dfrac` is an abbreviation of `display fraction`

Comment: Actually, I would have said it's short for "display-style fraction".